# How can I create a Form Builder group with an object?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder

Here is my component.ts:

```
 constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {}

  formobject = {} as GKCLForm1;
  gkclForm1 = this.fb.group({
    gcklform1 : this.fb.control(this.formobject)
  });
```

And here the component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="gkclForm1">
  <label>
    info:
    <input type="text" formControlName="gcklform1.info">
  </label>

  <label>
    id:
    <input type="text" formControlName="gcklform1.id">
  </label>
</form>
```

I have an object which type is GKCLForm1. info and id are the properties of that object.

And I want to create a form group from one object is it possible?
( I am using Angular 6 )

Comment: Not sure if it's possible. Why exactly do you want to do this though?

Comment: Read this: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms to understand Angular Reactive Forms.

Comment: I tried to make your question easer to understand, but please review my changes, and maybe improve it yourself, too. It is simply hard to grasp what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what it is that you're trying to achieve here. Generally, reactive forms are used so that they could yield a value(generally on submission) that is similar to data model.

There's a difference between primitive type values and complex type values and then there are different `AbstractControl`s used for both the types. If you have a complex type(say an Object), then you should be using a `FormGroup` for that as well. If you have a primitive type(a string, a number etc), you should be using a `FormControl`. I'm pretty sure that you won't be able to achieve anything out of it even if you try to use a `FormControl` for a complex data type.

For your case, I think you should be using a `FormGroup` for `gcklform1`.

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-eg) for your ref.